# Keep fixed symbol on a source text linked expression

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I have a *text layer* (property: *Source Text*) connected to a *slider control*, in the way that the slider goes from *0* to *40* and the text layer simply follows the same amount.

Now, I want to have a fixed symbol which it will be "*%*" next to the number but of course with the current expression:

> effect("Slider Control")("Slider")

It is not possible to have a symbol since the expression tells the text layer to follow the value of the slider.

Must be super simple but I don't have the knowledge to fix the expression.

---

**The final result would be the text layer going from 0% to 40%**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add text items together in Javascript is super easy, you just use the `+` operator, which is 'overloaded' so that when the either term in an expression `x + y` is a string, the output is the first and second terms concatenated, as a string.

So you can just use `+ "%"` to add a "%" symbol to the end of a number. Works for any character, e.g. `123 + "-foo"` would result in *123-foo*.

**TL;DR:**

```
effect("Slider Control")("Slider") + "%"
```

**Note** that the result of the slider will be a float (i.e. a number with lots of decimal places). That might not be what you're looking for. You can round it to an integer by using the `Math` functions, specifically `Math.round` (rounds to nearest integer) or `Math.floor` (always rounds down).

```
Math.round(effect("Slider Control")("Slider")) + "%"
```

**For extra credit**: If you did want some decimal places, say 2 decimal places, then multiply the number by 100, round it and then divide by 100:

```
Math.round(100 * effect("Slider Control")("Slider"))/100 + "%"
```

Comment: It was easy! Thank you so much, your answer will be really helpful when playing with this kind of string.

Comment: The Adobe docs for expressions are here: https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-basics.html I'd also suggest having a look at some basic JavaScript tutorials such as the ones at https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp Although aimed at Web development a lot of it is applicable for expressions, including some JS features not documented in the Adobe docs.